# How to scroll UITableView if its content size more than screen size?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

My problem is that how I can scroll through TableView if its content size more than screen size?

I have this code in my project (a lot of code, don't know which part makes me cry):

http://pastebin.com/BHXf9tER

Sometimes it goes well, but sometimes(and it's a big problem) it goes bad and I can't scroll :
In my project I use storyboard, so this is my view controller. https://i.stack.imgur.com/arb0h.png
What can I do? Please help me.

[QUESTION UPDATED]

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to accomplish. You don't need to mess with the tableView contentSize. The contenSize automatically changes to take into account the cell heights, section headers, etc. What does your tableView dataSource and delegate look like? How are you instantiating the table view cells?

Comment: updated post with all code of my view controller

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons can you please help me? Code provided at pastebin.

Comment: One glaring issue I see with the code is that `getAnswers` recreates the answers array over and over and over again.

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons Fixed this problem [pastebin link to my code](http://pastebin.com/EjPQvFep). What's next? How can it be scrolling now?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set the `frame` to the table view `contentSize`. Take out that code and then set the frame of the table view to the size of the screen in the nib/storyboard.

Comment: Sorry, I had deleted these lines of code before I posted, but nothing changed. I tried to set the frame of the table to the screen size but also nothing changed.

Comment: Its probably better if you update your answer with your latest code! :)